# SQLite3 and Rack Basic Auth cannot use username as execution parameter

Tags: ruby, sqlite, authentication, rack, sqlite3-ruby

Consider the following code snippet:

```rb
require "sqlite3"

db = SQLite3::Database.new "my.db"
p db.execute("select * from user where name = ?", ["my_user_name"])
```

This will outut the entry in the database where the user's name is "my_user_name". This works as intended.

Now consider this code snippet (config.ru):

```rb
require "rack/auth/basic"
require "sqlite3"

use Rack::Auth::Basic, "my authentication" do |username, password|
  p username
  p db.execute("select * from user where name = ?", [username])
end

run do |env|
  [200, {}, []]
end
```

When I send a request to this server:

```bash
curl -X POST -v -ujomy:abc123 localhost:9292 -d ''
```

I see the following output in the terminal where I started the server (using rackup):

```
"my_user_name"
[]
```

So I now do not get a result back from my sql query.

When I insert this line before the db.execute statement:

```rb
username = "my_user_name"
```

Now I actually get a result back.

Replacing `username` with `username.to_s` also does not work.

So it seems that using the username variable provided by Rack does not work with sqlite? How is this even possible as `username.class` is `String`? The `username.size` is equal to `"my_user_name".size` too.

Comment: @Casper `pp` shows the same output as `p`. I don't get what you're saying though. An array with one element also prints the same with `p` and `pp`

Comment: Did you double-check on the server that the user actually exists in the database? Do you have log files of the queries sent to the database, does the query look as expected in the logs?

Comment: @spickermann 
I did double check the user exists. Just added logging using `db.trace { |sql| p sql }`. This gave me the following output: `"select password from User where name = x'6a6f6d79' limit 1"` looks like this is where it is going wrong, but I still don't know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding issue. In this block `username` and `password` are encoded as "ASCII-8BIT".

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "my authentication" do |username, password|
  p username
  p db.execute("select * from user where name = ?", [username])
end
```

To resolve this you can change the encoding using `String#force_encoding` like so:

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "my authentication" do |username, password|
  p username
  p db.execute("select * from user where name = ?", [username.force_encoding('UTF-8')])
end
```